# Editing a record, when not on the 'usual' rails edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a user model that can be edited on the usual rails edit path.

However, I want to allow a number of fields from the user model to be editable from the root.

I have tried putting the following code in the index page and it works except when there is a validation error on one of the fields. When this happens the user is routed to the usual user edit path.

How can I change this so that the user is routed back to index (with the error message) if they sent the request from the index page (but keep it so that the user is routed back to the edit path if that's where they were making the edit from?

Also, feels like I am hacking this and not doing it in the 'best practice' way - is there are better way of doing it.

Code I have copied from the edit path to the index page:

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user, :url => registration_path(current_user), :html => { :method => :put, :class => 'form-vertical ' }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
      <%= display_base_errors current_user %>
      <%= f.input :dry_fly, inline_label: 'I use dry flies', as: :boolean, label: false %>
      <%= f.input :wet_fly, inline_label: 'I use wet flies', as: :boolean, label: false %>
      <%= f.input :lure, inline_label: 'I use lures', as: :boolean, label: false %>
      <%= f.input :still_water, inline_label: 'I fish lakes', as: :boolean, label: false %>
      <%= f.input :river, inline_label: 'I fish rivers', as: :boolean, label: false %>
      <%= f.input :current_password, :hint => "we need your current password to confirm your changes", :required => true %>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Update', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
```

RegistrationsController#update :

```
def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
      yield resource if block_given?
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

**Looks like Kirti Thorat's response is the right way to go - but I can't see from the devise controller where it defines what route should be used if the validation fails?**

Comment: What does the controller do when there's a validation error?

Comment: I've added the registrations#update method to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but for that you first need to check the HTTP Referer which will give you where the request came from and accordingly you can render your view in the `update` action. for eg:

When your update fails, you can render the appropriate edit user path by checking the referer 
as shown below

```
if URI(request.referer).path == edit_user_path 
  render :edit              ### Specify appropriate action
else
  render :index            ### Specify appropriate action
end
```